# RewriteRule problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using commands below in .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule . index.php 
RewriteRule ^(design|JS|css|images|remoteLibraries)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)$ index.php?action=$2
```

When I run http://my.url/home/ in my browser and just print $_GET i get this:

```
Array ( [action] => )
```

Whan am I doing wrong?

---

I get

```
Array ( [action] => php )
```

and rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing ^ at the beginning .. stupid me :)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?action=$1
```